# convert multiple coulmns into the categories of one column in pandas

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning, one-hot-encoding, data-preprocessing

This is a dataset which is converted using one hot encoding, 0 means no and 1 means yes

**data:**

| ID | Red | Blue | Green | Yellow | Orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1002 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1003 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1004 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1005 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

How to convert the above one hot encoded dataset into the below one in Pandas

**Expected output:**

| ID | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Red |
| 1001 | Green |
| 1001 | Orange |
| 1002 | Blue |
| 1002 | Yellow |
| 1003 | Yellow |
| 1003 | Orange |
| 1005 | Red |
| 1005 | Yellow |

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `.dot`

```
df.set_index('ID',inplace=True)
res = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').explode().reset_index(name='Colour')
```

---

**res:**

```
    ID  colour
0   1001    Red
1   1001    Green
2   1001    Orange
3   1002    Blue
4   1002    Yellow
5   1003    Yellow
6   1003    Orange
7   1004    
8   1005    Red
9   1005    Yellow
```

If you want to drop element at `index 7` containing nothing then do

```
res = res.replace('', np.nan).dropna()
```